# How to use getaddrinfo to connect to a server using the external IP?

Tags: c, sockets, getaddrinfo

I'm writing a small C client/server application, but I cannot make the connection work when using the external IP address. The code for both client and server is taken from [here](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/syscalls.html#getaddrinfo), in particular the clients do:

```
    char *default_server_name = "localhost";
    char *server_name = NULL;
    int nport = DEFAULT_DAMA_PORT;
    char port[15];

    // Parse the command line options
    if (parse_options(argc, argv, &server_name, &nport) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (server_name == NULL) {
        server_name = default_server_name;
    }

    snprintf(port, 15, "%d", nport);

    // Connect to the server
    int client_socket;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(server_name, port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        exit(1);
    }

    for (p=servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((client_socket = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
#ifdef DEBUG
            perror("socket");
#endif
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(client_socket, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(client_socket);
#ifdef DEBUG
            perror("connect");
#endif
            continue;
        }

        // Connected succesfully!
        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        // The loop wasn't able to connect to the server
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't connect to the server\n.");
        exit(1);
    }
```

While the server:

```
    int nport;
    char port[15];
    if (parse_options(argc, argv, &nport) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    snprintf(port, 15, "%d", nport);

    int server_socket;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        exit(1);
    }

    for (p=servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((server_socket = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
#ifdef DEBUG
            perror("socket");
#endif
            continue;
        }

        if (bind(server_socket, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(server_socket);
#ifdef DEBUG
            perror("bind");
#endif
            continue;
        }

        // We binded successfully!
        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to bind socket\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    int pl_one, pl_two;
    socklen_t pl_one_len, pl_two_len;
    struct sockaddr_in pl_one_addr, pl_two_addr;

    if (listen(server_socket, 2) < 0) {
        fatal_error("Error in syscall listen.", 2);
    }

    // Get the two clients connections.
    pl_one_len = sizeof(pl_one_addr);
    pl_one = accept(server_socket,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&pl_one_addr,
                    &pl_one_len);
    if (pl_one < 0) {
        fatal_error("Error in syscall accept.", 3);
    }

    pl_two_len = sizeof(pl_two_addr);
    pl_two = accept(server_socket,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&pl_two_addr,
                    &pl_two_len);
    if (pl_two < 0) {
        fatal_error("Error in syscall accept.", 3);
    }
```

If I specify the IP of my machine in the command line, and hence the `server_name` in the clients is set to a string like `151.51.xxx.xxx`, then the sockets cannot connect to the server. Also using `127.0.0.1` shows the same behaviour, which makes me think that when the documentation states:

> The host name that you're interested in goes in the nodename
>   parameter. The address can be either a host name, like
>   "www.example.com", or an IPv4 or IPv6 address (passed as a string).

it's just joking.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Could there be some problem with firewall etc. that is preventing the clients to connect using the IP addresses?

Note: I've already searched a lot for this problem and some people say to avoid using `getaddrinfo` at all and directly fill with `INADDR_ANY`, but the `getaddrinfo` documentation states that passing `NULL` as `nodename` should already fill the address with `INADDR_ANY`, so I don't see why should I use the old method when the new one does this automatically.

Comment: For the server part to work as expected (to be able accept connections) you have to add calls to `listen()` and `accept()`. You might like to read on chapter 9.15 and chapter 9.1.

Comment: @alk I obviously do have calls to `listen` and `accept`(otherwise how come the server works if the client use `localhost` as `server_name`?). I'll add them to the question anyway.

Comment: Is the server behind a router? Are the required ports opened or forwarded?

Comment: Some older ’share the internet’-boxes cannot do what you seem to be trying to do. That is, if you have setup port-forwarding, it will only work if you try to connect from a machine that is outside of your local network.

Comment: @typ1232 I have the router, and I think it is probably blocking connections to most ports... Still I don't get why passing `127.0.0.1` is different than passing `localhost`. Anyway it seems like the problem is not the code but the router configuration. @Sudhee No, if I use `localhost` it works, if I use *anything* else it doesn't work.

Comment: To what ip-address does `localhost` resolve?

Comment: Sry, but you did not mention it worked for `localhost` in you OP.

Comment: @Bakuriu 127.0.0.1/"localhost" is the local loopback, it is a redirection of the OS! this will not go over the router, whereas an external ip will. You need to open the ports in your router configuration

Comment: @Bakuriu: tyring to localize the issue, so you are saying if you use "localhost" it works fine, and if you use "127.0.0.1" it fails? If so, it wont be router config (may be that too later, but this is different).  Are you sure your parse_options is not messing up the IP Address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in comments you are trying to connect to a server that is located in a network behind a router.

`127.0.0.1` or `localhost` are redirections of the operating system and will not go over the router. That's why it worked for you.

If you specify an external ip address, the connection is made via the router and the ports that you use need to be forwarded in the router configuration. Any normal home internet end user router blocks incoming connections from any port by default.